# HTML Agility - Only one record is being found in the code below

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to obtain ALL of the div tags with a certain class.

The code below runs fine, but only one record comes back.

What am I doing wrong?

```
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                string html = client.DownloadString("https://myurl.com");

                doc.LoadHtml(html);

                var findDivs = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(d =>
                            d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("list-mode-table-wrapper")
                        ).Select(x => x).ToList();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using SelectNodes to get all the div tags with a specific class name.

```
    var findDivs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='list-mode-table-wrapper']")?.ToList();
```

SelectNodes uses an XPath that searches the entire document when you use //. This will search the entire page for divs that have that class name. For anything under div with that class, you can use / to specify the element you need under it (`("//div[@class='xyz']/table/tbody/etc")`).

Since SelectNodes return a null if nothing is found, you can use error checking to make sure findDivs is not null when you continue to work with it.

Comment: I tried that and still one record. Can the website block html agility from working? This table row is underneath each div tag: primary-row-tr

Comment: Have you actually checked the InnerHtml of `doc.DocumentNode` to see if there actually are two divs with same class name?

Comment: I tried this `     var findDivs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='list-mode-table-wrapper']/table/tbody/tr[@class='primary-row-tr']").ToList();`

Comment: without seeing the document, there is not much i can suggest as to what will work and what wont. Use `debugger` and `Immediate window` to see number of nodes you get for each of the queries (//div[] then try, //div[class]/table). Check innerHtml to see the actual document and continue down. If there are extra tags in between, use `//` instead of single `/`

Comment: You are right! There is only 1. But there are 31 in the inspect of F12. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you email me and I work with you with the specific website? Not sure if this is possible?

Comment: [Answer i posted on another site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59940573/1390548) where HAP is not able to access data because it hasnt been rendered.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I might look at it later, but right now I found another site with the data I need and it appears easier to cycle etc. Thanks again.