# Html Agility Pack xpath throws null exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse [this page](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/4000646776468.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.706b7aa3keAp3L&algo_pvid=c43ec471-4950-4e91-b15e-11c1e3e4c734&algo_expid=c43ec471-4950-4e91-b15e-11c1e3e4c734-0&btsid=ed926caa-d6ae-47af-86d8-acf7db591995&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4,searchweb201603_53).
To select the nodes I need I use XPath, my XPath works fine in my browser, but when using it in my project it returns a null exception.
The XPath for title works fine, but the one for description does not.

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument document = web.Load("http://nl.aliexpress.com/item/4000646776468.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.531f7aa3iGAnCb&algo_pvid=0b20aa21-fd7f-4826-81a5-c9aac5254da8&algo_expid=0b20aa21-fd7f-4826-81a5-c9aac5254da8-0&btsid=8849a0ec-e95d-447f-a6f9-34dcd58f1381&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4,searchweb201603_53");
        ProductModel product = new ProductModel { 
             Title = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head/title").InnerText,
             Description = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/p[2]").InnerText};
        return View(product);
```

Comment: This could be due to a script dynamically creating that node in the browser, but not in your project.

Comment: what is the description supposed to be ? from that url

Comment: @Jawad the description is supposed to select the first descriptional box. The first line of text is "Ontworpen door Apple" (that's dutch)

Comment: yeah, that, you wont be able to. Html you are parsing is base html without the data that is rendered by browsers. See my [response to another pos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59940573/1390548) similar to this.

Comment: @Jawad do you recommand an alternative for hap that do run all javascript rendering?

Comment: I have not come across a solution that does that. You can do that but it requires working with tools outside of HAP. If you are using Console Application, it wont work but for WinForm, there are a few solutions you might be able to find on StackOverflow.

Comment: Here is what HAP says about it: https://html-agility-pack.net/from-browser but I've never actually done it that way... I have done it with various other methods, including the old `WebBrowser` control in a console application... I won't recommend that however, only because it's based on IE... the new `WebView` and `WebView2` are based on Edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indeed turned out to be a problem with content being dynamically rendered.
For those who come across the some problem, take a look at selenium if you are using c#.
I switched to node using the puppeteer libary.